# How to calculate a ratio of how many users have a specific value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a user_id column (with multiple rows per unique user) and I have another column for the link they clicked on (one row per link but one user might have clicked on several links). 
I want to know the % of users who clicked on link:

1,

2,

3,

and more importantly those that clinked on all 1, 2 and 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"User_ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
                   "Link": [6, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3]})
print(df)

    Link    User_ID
0   6       1
1   2       1
2   4       1
3   1       2
4   2       2
5   1       3
6   3       3

# get overall user count
n_users = df["User_ID"].unique().size

# define helper function to calculate percentage
def get_percentage(x):
    bool_links = df["Link"].isin(x)
    count_users = df.loc[bool_links, "User_ID"].unique().size
    return count_users / float(n_users)

# print percentages
for link in [[1], [2], [3], [1, 2, 3]]:
    print("Link", link, get_percentage(link))

Link [1] 0.6666666666666666
Link [2] 0.6666666666666666
Link [3] 0.3333333333333333
Link [1, 2, 3] 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pansen.
the get overall user count doesn't work unfortunately I get the following message:
'int' object is not callable

Comment: @Pierre So this `df["User_ID"].unique().size` causes the error? Please check that you don't have `size()`. What pandas/python version do you use?